# OpenSSL 3.0.2 PKCS12_parse Failure

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, network-programming

We're migrating to Openssl 3.0.2, currently experiencing connection issues between a 3.0.2 server and a 1.1.1g client.

According to the logs collected we seem to be having an issue with the loading of the legacy providers.
We are loading both the default and legacy providers programmatically as per the steps outlined in the Wiki for OpenSSL 3.0 - 6.2 Providers without issue.

We are seeing the following error..

error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:346:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
PKCS12_parse() failed = 183. (Using GetLastError from errhandlingapi.h, the 183 error code is obtained)

Worth mentioning that we are only seeing this issue occur when the server is a Windows 2012 server.

Both default and legacy providers are loaded without issue at start.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed by Liam, OpenSSL 3.0 does not support *by default * legacy algorithm RC2-40-CBC.

Fortunately, the **legacy** library is included in the bin folder in my distribution (https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html ; full list https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries).

So my steps to resolve were

1. Set OPENSSL_MODULES
2. Add -legacy option

Set the variable OPENSSL_MODULES

```
SET OPENSSL_MODULES=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin
```

Without -legacy option:

```
D:\sources\en.Resilience_Temy\config\certificates>openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12 -out saxserver.crt
Enter Import Password:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
Error outputting keys and certificates
58630000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

With -legacy option:

```
D:\sources\en.Resilience_Temy\config\certificates>openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12 -out server.crt -legacy
Enter Import Password:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

And file is generated successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to `RC2-40-CBC` more specifically `RC2` being disabled by either AD Policy or the OpenSSL library because it is deemed too weak a cipher.

A very simple way to test this:

- open wordpad and create a file with `hello world` in it
- run `openssl enc -e -rc4-40 -K 1234567890 -in hellowworld.txt -out hellowworld.txt`

Assuming this generates an error then this would be stronger evidence that `RC2-40` is disabled. From there you can either:

- Determine if AD or the OpenSSL library (compile flags) is blocking its use and enable it
- Use stronger ciphers in your P12 generation (suggested route)

Comment: I am not able to produce the test as the built in openssl 1.1.1e for perl overtakes the 3.0.2 version which i built off of github. I will try to strong ciphers as suggested thank you.

Comment: Currently we are trying to use the cert from memory.  
First we create a memory store, then we pass the desired cert context to the store.
Then we export via PFXExportCertStoreEx and pass it into a CRYPT_DATA_BLOB.
Using d2i_PKCS12_bio to pass the cert to the PKCS12 object, and then use PKCS12_parse.
I'm not sure where to use the stronger cipher?